# Preventing barcode scanning using Ml-kit from triggering a function call twice

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Google's ML-Kit barcode scanning plugin along with Flutter's default camera plugin for my project. From my testing, I can see that if I scan a QR code with the current implementation that navigates you to another screen, then navigate back, the whole navigation process is triggered again. Using logging, I've found that it's probably caused because the  `parseImageForQRCode()` function is triggered very fast between `_processCameraImage()` calls made by the camera's image stream. This in turn doesn't give enough time to the `parseImageForQRCode()` function to update the `_isBusy` variable and basically lock the function like a mutex. Is there a recommended way for avoiding such race cases?

camera_screen.dart:

```
class CameraComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraComponent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraComponent> createState() => _CameraComponentState();
}

class _CameraComponentState extends State<CameraComponent>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraCubit get _cubit => context.read<CameraCubit>();
  CameraController? _controller;
  final BarcodeScanner _barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner();
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;
  CameraDescription? _camera;
  final ArtworkRepository _artworkRepository = getIt<ArtworkRepository>();

  Future<CameraDescription> getCamera() async {
    // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
    final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

    // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
    return cameras.first;
  }

  void _navigateToArtworkDetailsById({required int artworkId}) {
    context.navigator.pushNamed(
      ArtworkViewScreen.path,
      arguments: <String, dynamic>{
        'artworkId': artworkId,
        'source': ArtworkViewSourceScreen.QRScan.name
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _cubit.init();
    startCameraSetup();
  }

  Future<void> startCameraSetup() async {
    _canProcess = true;
    _camera = await getCamera();

    //todo:sp handle camera being null
    if (_camera == null) {
      log('camera was null!');
      displayErrorDialog('Camera Error',
          'Looks like the camera is busy or unavailable! Please try again later.');
      return;
    }

    _controller = CameraController(
      _camera!,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );

    _controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }

    final Uint8List bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    final InputImageRotation? imageRotation =
        InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(_camera!.sensorOrientation);

    if (imageRotation == null) {
      return;
    }

    final InputImageFormat? inputImageFormat =
        InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw);

    if (inputImageFormat == null) {
      return;
    }

    final List<InputImagePlaneMetadata> planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final InputImageData inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    final InputImage inputImage =
        InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

    parseImageForQRCode(inputImage);
  }

  Future parseImageForQRCode(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (!_canProcess) {
      return;
    }

    if (_isBusy) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isBusy = true;
    });
    final List<Barcode> barcodes =
        await _barcodeScanner.processImage(inputImage);

    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty) {
      final Barcode qrcode = barcodes[0];
      if (qrcode.rawValue != null) {
        try {
          final int artworkId = int.parse(qrcode.rawValue!.split('_')[1]);

          _controller!.stopImageStream();

          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
            _navigateToArtworkDetailsById(
              artworkId: artworkId,
            );
            await _artworkRepository.scanArtwork(id: artworkId);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          displayErrorDialog('Oops',
              'Looks like something went wrong! Please make sure you\'re using a valid QR code & try again.');
        }
      }
    }
    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void displayErrorDialog(String title, String msg) {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        content: Text(msg),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('Ok'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    cleanup();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future cleanup() async {
    _canProcess = false;
    _isBusy = false;
    _barcodeScanner.close();
    if (_controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      try {
        await _controller?.stopImageStream();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
    await _controller?.dispose();
    _controller = null;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    log(state.name);

    // final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;
    // // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    // if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    //   return;
    // }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      log('inactive being called');
      cleanup();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      log('on resume called');
      startCameraSetup();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<CameraCubit, CameraState>(
        listener: (BuildContext context, CameraState state) {
          state.maybeWhen(
            initCamera: (List<CameraDescription> cameras) {},
            orElse: () {},
          );
        },
        builder: (BuildContext context, CameraState state) {
          return state.maybeWhen(
            initCamera: (_) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text(
                    'Take a picture',
                    style: montserratRegular15.copyWith(color: AppColors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                body: Stack(
                  children: [
                    if (_controller?.value.isInitialized == true)
                      CameraPreview(_controller!)
                    else
                      const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: AppColors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 130,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Scan a QR code or take a photo of\nthe artwork',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: montserratRegular15.copyWith(
                            color: AppColors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
                            if (!_controller!.value.isInitialized) {
                              displayErrorDialog('Camera Error',
                                  'Looks like the camera is busy or unavailable. Please try again later.');
                              return;
                            }
                            await _controller!.stopImageStream();
                            final XFile image =
                                await _controller!.takePicture();
                            final Uint8List bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
                            final String base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);

                            final int artworkId =
                                await _cubit.imageSearchByBase64(
                              base64Image: base64Image,
                            );
                            if (_cubit.state is ArtworkIdFound$) {
                              _navigateToArtworkDetailsById(
                                artworkId: artworkId,
                              );
                              _cubit.init();
                            }
                          },
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/icons/shutter_icon.png',
                            height: 72,
                            width: 72,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
                        child: Image.asset('assets/icons/b_logo_grey.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            loading: () => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: AppColors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Performing image recognition...',
                  style: montserratRegular15,
                )
              ],
            ),
            initial: () => const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: AppColors.red,
              ),
            ),
            artworkIdError: () {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Failed to recognize artwork!',
                    style: montserratRegular15,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
                    child: AppButton(
                      onTap: () {
                        _cubit.init();
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      text: 'Retry',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            orElse: () {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: AppColors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Performing image recognition...',
                    style: montserratRegular15,
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check the whole code, but generally I would add the flag on the top of the callback function (and check it there, too), why not set `isBusy` in `_processCameraImage` and set it to false in a finally block?

Comment: @voidvoid Unfortunately, the additional check doesn't help, as soon as i navigate back the block containing the navigation is executed again. I even tried calling `cleanUp()` right after finding a qr code and then calling `startCameraSetup()` after the navigation is finished (using `then`) but nothing.

As for the finally block, the `_isBusy=false` should run either way at the end of the function, no? If so, isn't it redundant?